# unsupported_response_type error for Android Google authentication

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, xamarin, google-oauth

I am trying to authenticate my app user with his/her google account but after the sign in, it shows up unsupported_response_type on the screen. The authentication was success but I have no idea why the response is not redirecting to the required screen.

Is it fault on my code implementation side or is it some authentication problem with google. I did it using OAuth2Authenticator class.

with client id, scope, authorizeUrl and redirectUrl parameters.